# ModuleNotFoundError - Installing PyCharm and Anaconda

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I'm setting up PyCharm and Anaconda on a new computer and am running into errors saying modules are not found.

I've confirmed that the module, Pandas is installed. When I go to Terminal and 'pip install pandas' it says Requirement Already satisfied. Similarly, when I go to the Anaconda Prompt and install there it also says it is already installed.

Within PyCharm my interpreter is set to C:\Users<username>\anaconda3\envs<ProjectName>\python.exe but when I see all the packages listed under that interpreter its missing all the ones I installed.

How can I get the modules I've installed via Anaconda to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

you should select the right interpreter in pycharm :
file > python Interpreter > setting > add > and then from Conda Environment you can pass your environment path and use it.
usefull links:
[configure python interpreter on pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) and
[configure python interpreter on VScode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Comment: ask if you need more detail, but I think it's clear.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. The interpreter was referencing a python.exe file in some virtual env I had created, but if I just switched it to the C:\Users<username>\anaconda3\python.exe it now seems to be working. I think the former was preventing it from recognizing all the modules.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).